# The sum of Cotes coefficients

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, calculator

Newton-Cotes coefficients is as follows
$$
C_{i}^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-i}}{i !(n-i) ! n} \int_{0}^{n} \prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j \neq i}}^{n}(t-j) d t
$$
How can we prove that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^nC_i^{(n)}=1
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  I bet you've lost count of how many times you've repeated the same. Too many new users just state "This is the problem, how to solve?".

Comment: Lots of times for you. But, for each new user, it's the first time that they see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the polynomial

$$
F_i(t) =\frac{(-1)^{n-i}}{i !(n-i) ! n} \prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j \neq i}}^{n}(t-j) d t
$$

And look at the values for $t = 0,1,2,\dots, n$. It is only non-zero at $t = i$, and the value equals $\frac{1}{n}$.

Therefore

$\sum_{i=0}^n F_i(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, and equals $\frac{1}{n}$ at all integer nodes $t=0,1,2,\dots, n$, thus it must be constant $\frac{1}{n}$. Its integral equals one.